# MOSFET, the effect of the gate voltage

Tags: voltage, mosfet

[image]

Here the gate voltage is 5V and lots of the 12V input voltage stays across drain and source.

[image]

Here the gate voltage is 12V and still some voltage stays across drain and source but this time smaller.

I knew that gate voltage just opens the path between drain and source making them act as short circuit. But here, I saw that

1) Apparently drain to source is not short circuted because there is some voltage drop in both cases. **Why voltage drops across drain and source?**

2) **Why applying 5V or 12V to gate makes a difference? Isn't only job of gate voltage is to *open/close* the drain-source connection?**

p.s : both are simulation results using proteus.

Comment: You've created a source follower. Look at the Vgs value. You'll find a graph in the datasheet that shows what happens as that varies.

Comment: @PhilG is it about not connecting source to ground directly? Because after your comment I just remembered that and connected motor before drain instead of after source and connected source to ground. Now the voltage across the motor is 12V either I close SW1 or SW2.

Comment: *I knew that gate voltage just opens the path between drain and source* What gate voltage? The gate voltage **with respect to the source voltage** (Vgs) is determining it, not the gate voltage with respect to ground.

Comment: @Huisman I guess you are right and the problem is about that, see my comment above. So, in order to use an N channel mosfet as switch, it should be used such that it's source is connected to ground directly and the load is connected to drain, right?

Comment: It's not a requirement but it makes it much easier to drive if you use it that way, yes. There can be cases where you would want to use it as a high-side switch, but this isn't one of them.